# facing issue while running docker container from docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

[image: This is error i am gettingstrong text]

Getting this :- error while reading the file "./inputdata": open ./inputdata: no such file or directory is coming when i am running docker container using docker-compose.yml file

How i create ./inputdata file for the same in docker-compose.yml file, I am new to docker please help for the same

[image: This is my docker-compose.yml file]

This is my docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Please add more details, this doesn't explain what is the setup. Where is the file? How are you reading the file? Did you map the file using a Volume or did you copt the file using a Dockerfile? What docker image are you running?

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani thank you for your comment/Suggestion have map the Volume with "inputdata file" with image-container and my issue resolved, The issue I'm facing because the container need that file for running. Sorry for the late reply..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi sorry for the late reply, The issue occurred because the custom image I'm using need a "inputdata file" with some index based entries in it like (1, 45) (2, 65) and so on
before running the container , so I add/map/copy that file i.e inputdata file in my docker-compose.yml , See below for the same.

```
*mycsvserver:
image: "MY_IMAGE_NAME"
container_name: csvserver_container
ports:
- 9393:9300
volumes:
- ./inputFile:/csvserver/inputdata*
```

OR we can run that container using below command :-

**docker run -d -v /home/testuser/inputFile:/csvserver/inputdata <MY_IMAGE_NAME>**

Note: Here we have created a inputFile with some indexed based entries in it and map that volume with our image with inputdata file.